# Trying to get a certain user by username into a variable

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

Im trying to add a user profile page to a webpage so i need to get the details for a user by username. Im using $stateparams which is getting the username fine.

The im using this function which is throwing an error

```
      $scope.ourUser = Users.get({
            username: $stateParams.username
        });
```

Error

```
[$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array
```

Controller code seems alright

```
angular.module('savings').controller('SavingsController', ['$scope',  '$http', '$timeout', '$stateParams', '$location', '$window','$state' , 'Authentication', 'Savings', 'FileUploader', 'Posts', 'Users',
function($scope,  $http, $timeout, $stateParams,  $location, $window, $state, Authentication, Savings, FileUploader, Posts, Users) {
```

Ive edited the question to simplify it as the Posts call wasnt where the problem is.

Ive added this to the services

```
userByUsername: {
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/users/:userName',
    isArray: true
  }
```

Comment: And what you get if you di the request that you're doing in your code?: http://localhost:3000/api/savings/of/user._id

Comment: It works. i get a list of JSON items. The problem seems the be the ourUser variable. Its not getting the user to get the id.

Comment: It doesn't, because you want an user object, not a list of objects... don't you?.

Comment: I thought i first want a user object then a list of the users items which would be an array. edit - isee what you mean. yes  iwant an object.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a resource you have a property isArray available  like this :

```
'search':   {method:'GET', isArray:true,....}
```

Set it to true when your service return a list or it will fail with that message.

This means that the variable ourUser will be an array of [expected] one user.

Comment: whats the name of the actual function i would be calling. I believe im doing something like this countUsersToday: {
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/users/userCountToday',
        isArray: false
      } but what would i call it in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Ok ive removed the whole posts call as it was the problem was before that was called. Its the User call that is causing the problem.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource $resource define by default a get method that is made to fetch one object. So either overwrite it or change it.